# Iron & Windows: Error code 3221226505 when running ROS 2 node with ros2 run

Tags: ros2, image, windows, errors, troubleshooting

I am trying implementing the tutorial of ["Using quality-of-service settings for lossy networks"](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Demos/Quality-of-Service.html).
When I try to run the showimage node in the image_tools package using the ros2 run command:

```
ros2 run image_tools showimage
```

I get the following error:

```
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 3221226505
```

The steps to reproduce are:

1. Build the image_tools package
2. Source the setup script
3. Run `ros2 run image_tools showimage`

Then I see the above error code 3221226505 printed, as followed:

```
D:\Professional\ROS2\Tutorials\demos\image_tools>ros2 run image_tools showimage
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 3221226505
```

I have tried rebuilding the package but the issue persists.

I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting this error when running ROS 2 nodes.

Comment: Please edit your question so people can help you better. Can you expand your question to include more about what environment you're running on? What version of the code you're running? What else is running on your system? Does it have the same behavior with other image sources? What is the minimal system to reproduce your error?